# ERRO 0b1 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=54.1.1.1:40057

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

HLF 1.4.6 version

I am getting the below mentioned error on enabling backup of my blockchain system which is deployed on  distributed AWS network where I have five VMs 3 for organizations 1 for orderers 1 for SDK.  Below mentioned error is coming in orderer.network.com.

> 2021-02-22 04:51:59.576 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0b1
> TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate
> server=Orderer remoteaddress=54.156.31.171:40054

But still read and write operation to blockchain from CLI as well as SDK are working.  But still this error is in the background which worries me a lot.

Adding docker_compose_CLI code for first OU which is running on one VM and similar code for other 2 OUs in 2 more VMs

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  peer0.notary.veritable.com:
  ca.notary.veritable.com:

networks:
  veritable-network:

services:
  ca.notary.veritable.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.notary.veritable.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.notary.veritable.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/5ac95636048f76831391e7112c75fe9200ef2d42a41234b8bab_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/notary.veritable.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./data/ca-notary/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/
    container_name: ca.notary.veritable.com
    networks:
      - veritable-network

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=adminN0
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=a1adminN0
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - veritable-network


  peer0.notary.veritable.com:
    container_name: peer0.notary.veritable.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.notary.veritable.com
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=adminN0
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=a1adminN0
    networks:
      - veritable-network
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4.6
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.notary.veritable.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=notaryMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/notary.veritable.com/peers/peer0.notary.veritable.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/notary.veritable.com/peers/peer0.notary.veritable.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/notary.veritable.com/peers/peer0.notary.veritable.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/notary.veritable.com/users/Admin@notary.veritable.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../veritable-chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - peer0.notary.veritable.com
      - peer1.notary.veritable.com
      - ca.notary.veritable.com
    networks:
      - veritable-network




Adding docker_compose_etcdraft file code which is running on 2nd VM

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.veritable.com:
  orderer2.veritable.com:
  orderer3.veritable.com:

networks:
  veritable-network:

services:
  orderer.veritable.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer.veritable.com
    networks:
    - veritable-network
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer.veritable.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer.veritable.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.veritable.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
        - ./data/orderer:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 7050:7050


  orderer2.veritable.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer2.veritable.com
    networks:
    - veritable-network
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer2.veritable.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer2.veritable.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.veritable.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
        - ./data/orderer2:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 8050:7050

  orderer3.veritable.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer3.veritable.com
    networks:
    - veritable-network
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer3.veritable.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/veritable.com/orderers/orderer3.veritable.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/`enter code here`tls
        - orderer3.veritable.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
        - ./data/orderer3:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 9050:7050
```

Comment: Not sure where in your  backup process you are actually connecting to Fabric nodes?

Comment: @GariSingh: I have added docker_compose_cli.yaml file code for only 1 Peer of 1 organizations.  I have total 3 VMs for 3 organizations and two peers in each organization.

Comment: @GariSingh Also added code of docker_compose_etcdraft2.ymal file code for 3 orderers which is running on completely different VM.  My all orderers are running in one VM only.  So total 4 EC2 VM 3 for organizations and 1 for orderer.

Comment: @GariSingh If possible give me github ID i will share my github repository with you.

Comment: It is mastersingh24

Comment: @GariSingh, I have added you as contributor for all 4 repositories for 4 VMs

Comment: @GariSingh, Also added u in VeritableNWnew where my configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml are kept for channel artifacts and crypto materials. If you would like to check any particular details.

Comment: @GariSingh Request you to review all 4 repositories and suggest the changes.

Comment: @RicNitt, please help me here with some Solution.

Comment: @RicNtt, please help me here with some Solution.

Comment: I noticed TLS env variables were missing so added two below mention  but still facing the same error. FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlsca.notary.veritable.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/49f5191b90b3c9d1b1b9519eaa9244efdcd9d71b11dc64123c28e63f5565_sk
    ports:

Comment: And volumes now look like.                           volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/client.veritable.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/client.veritable.com/tlsca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls
      - ./data/ca-client/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/

Comment: Can anyone suggest